# DataFormatString in C# Rounding Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an issue that is currently causing the currency in my program to round. If it is a 7 digit number it automatically rounds it up and I can't understand the issue.

For example:

100000.99 will automatically round up to 100001.00 when it is stored in the DB.

However, if I have anything under six digits it is stored correctly.

```
[Display(Name = "PO Value")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
public float POValue { get; set; }
```

Any suggestion?

The application was built in Visual Studio 2010 using C# and the MVC4 engine.

Comment: I don't think this is a C# issue probably more like the 'width' on the column in SQL

Comment: You could try adding a `[DataType(DataType.Currency)]` to the property to see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael Coxon I have solved the issue!  Within the DB the column POValue was setup with a DataType as real.  Therefore the precision is only 7 which accounts my issues.  I am having it modified to the DataType float.